# Why is my png image data disappearing?

Tags: debian, hard-disk, corruption, png

I've been creating a few PNG images with some maps in the last days (using R). After the images are finished, I move them to a separate folder labeled "ok", so I don't get the risk of overwriting them later. However, some of these images are becoming completely white a few days later, others are returning to a previous state (with only a few layers of shapefiles on them), which I'm not even sure if I had generated at some point or not (I guess I did, since I did this to some of them). Even the white images retain their actual size in bytes, though they appear completely white in many programs.

`pngcheck` says about one of those images, one that's totally white -- supose the filename is `file.png`:

```
file.png  additional data after IEND chunk
ERROR: file.png
```

Running a histogram with ImageMagick on the same file returns:

```
convert file.png -define histogram:unique-colors=true -format %c histogram:info:-
   9000000: (255,255,255) #FFFFFF white
```

which means it really became all white (the original image is 3000x3000 pixels).

I'm using Debian 9. Last time I've ran a self-test on this HD (with gnome-disks), it said:

```
Disk is OK, 43 bad sectors.
```

Now I've ran the same test again, and it said the same thing. Which should mean no new bad sectors appeared. It's a usual HDD, not a SSD. Here's the full output:

[image: gnome-disks result's print screen]

And the results of `smartctl -a`:

```
smartctl 6.6 2016-05-31 r4324 [x86_64-linux-4.9.0-9-amd64] (local build)
Copyright (C) 2002-16, Bruce Allen, Christian Franke, www.smartmontools.org

=== START OF INFORMATION SECTION ===
Model Family:     Seagate Constellation ES (SATA)
Device Model:     ST32000644NS
Serial Number:    9WM0CKBJ
LU WWN Device Id: 5 000c50 01a8899f1
Firmware Version: GG15
User Capacity:    2,000,398,934,016 bytes [2.00 TB]
Sector Size:      512 bytes logical/physical
Rotation Rate:    7200 rpm
Device is:        In smartctl database [for details use: -P show]
ATA Version is:   ATA8-ACS T13/1699-D revision 4
SATA Version is:  SATA 2.6, 3.0 Gb/s (current: 3.0 Gb/s)
Local Time is:    Tue Jun  4 23:23:48 2019 -03
SMART support is: Available - device has SMART capability.
SMART support is: Enabled

=== START OF READ SMART DATA SECTION ===
SMART overall-health self-assessment test result: PASSED

General SMART Values:
Offline data collection status:  (0x82) Offline data collection activity
                    was completed without error.
                    Auto Offline Data Collection: Enabled.
Self-test execution status:      (   0) The previous self-test routine completed
                    without error or no self-test has ever 
                    been run.
Total time to complete Offline 
data collection:        (  609) seconds.
Offline data collection
capabilities:            (0x7b) SMART execute Offline immediate.
                    Auto Offline data collection on/off support.
                    Suspend Offline collection upon new
                    command.
                    Offline surface scan supported.
                    Self-test supported.
                    Conveyance Self-test supported.
                    Selective Self-test supported.
SMART capabilities:            (0x0003) Saves SMART data before entering
                    power-saving mode.
                    Supports SMART auto save timer.
Error logging capability:        (0x01) Error logging supported.
                    General Purpose Logging supported.
Short self-test routine 
recommended polling time:    (   1) minutes.
Extended self-test routine
recommended polling time:    ( 339) minutes.
Conveyance self-test routine
recommended polling time:    (   2) minutes.
SCT capabilities:          (0x10bd) SCT Status supported.
                    SCT Error Recovery Control supported.
                    SCT Feature Control supported.
                    SCT Data Table supported.

SMART Attributes Data Structure revision number: 10
Vendor Specific SMART Attributes with Thresholds:
ID# ATTRIBUTE_NAME          FLAG     VALUE WORST THRESH TYPE      UPDATED  WHEN_FAILED RAW_VALUE
  1 Raw_Read_Error_Rate     0x000f   075   063   044    Pre-fail  Always       -       32950755
  3 Spin_Up_Time            0x0003   100   100   000    Pre-fail  Always       -       0
  4 Start_Stop_Count        0x0032   100   100   020    Old_age   Always       -       976
  5 Reallocated_Sector_Ct   0x0033   099   099   036    Pre-fail  Always       -       43
  7 Seek_Error_Rate         0x000f   081   060   030    Pre-fail  Always       -       130556579
  9 Power_On_Hours          0x0032   080   080   000    Old_age   Always       -       17849
 10 Spin_Retry_Count        0x0013   100   100   097    Pre-fail  Always       -       0
 12 Power_Cycle_Count       0x0032   100   100   020    Old_age   Always       -       975
184 End-to-End_Error        0x0032   100   100   099    Old_age   Always       -       0
187 Reported_Uncorrect      0x0032   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       0
188 Command_Timeout         0x0032   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       0
189 High_Fly_Writes         0x003a   098   098   000    Old_age   Always       -       2
190 Airflow_Temperature_Cel 0x0022   059   047   045    Old_age   Always       -       41 (Min/Max 24/42)
191 G-Sense_Error_Rate      0x0032   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       1
192 Power-Off_Retract_Count 0x0032   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       31
193 Load_Cycle_Count        0x0032   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       977
194 Temperature_Celsius     0x0022   041   053   000    Old_age   Always       -       41 (0 18 0 0 0)
195 Hardware_ECC_Recovered  0x001a   024   018   000    Old_age   Always       -       32950755
197 Current_Pending_Sector  0x0012   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       0
198 Offline_Uncorrectable   0x0010   100   100   000    Old_age   Offline      -       0
199 UDMA_CRC_Error_Count    0x003e   200   200   000    Old_age   Always       -       0

SMART Error Log Version: 1
No Errors Logged

SMART Self-test log structure revision number 1
Num  Test_Description    Status                  Remaining  LifeTime(hours)  LBA_of_first_error
# 1  Short offline       Completed without error       00%     17849         -
# 2  Short offline       Completed without error       00%     15687         -
# 3  Extended offline    Aborted by host               50%     14014         -
# 4  Extended offline    Aborted by host               90%     13928         -
# 5  Short offline       Completed without error       00%     13928         -
# 6  Short offline       Completed without error       00%     13927         -
# 7  Short offline       Aborted by host               80%     13927         -
# 8  Short offline       Completed without error       00%      2881         -
# 9  Short offline       Completed without error       00%      2878         -
#10  Short offline       Completed without error       00%      1562         -
#11  Short offline       Completed without error       00%       151         -
#12  Short offline       Completed without error       00%        48         -

SMART Selective self-test log data structure revision number 1
 SPAN  MIN_LBA  MAX_LBA  CURRENT_TEST_STATUS
    1        0        0  Not_testing
    2        0        0  Not_testing
    3        0        0  Not_testing
    4        0        0  Not_testing
    5        0        0  Not_testing
Selective self-test flags (0x0):
  After scanning selected spans, do NOT read-scan remainder of disk.
If Selective self-test is pending on power-up, resume after 0 minute delay.
```

What may be going on?

Comment: possible virus infection

Comment: a disk with bad sectors is ok?! `smartctl -a`? any chance you moved/copied files while they were being written to? if SSD I'd have suspected TRIM corruption bug that was in 5.1.x kernel recently. also had a RAID6 corruption bug.

Comment: @jsotola What to do about it?

Comment: @frostschutz I didn't moved or copied the files after they were moved to 'ok' folder. From this folder I annexed them to e-mail messages, and I still can recover them from my e-mail box. It's not a SSD, as I said.